# Abstract/array issues with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, silverlight, protobuf-net

I'm having trouble trying to deserialise an array of objects which derive from the same **abstract** base class and serialised with **AsReference** on. The following reproduces my issue:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(1,typeof(A))]
    [ProtoInclude(2, typeof(B))]
    public abstract class Base
    {}

    [ProtoContract]
    public class A:Base
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int J
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class B : Base
    { }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Obj
    {
        [ProtoMember(1,AsReference=true,DynamicType=true)]
        public Base[] array = new Base[] { new A(), new B() };
    }
```

Then attempt to de/serialise like so:

```
        Obj bob = new Obj();

        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(m, bob);
            m.Position = 0;
            var clone = Serializer.Deserialize<Obj>(m);
        }
```

Depending on the ProtoMember options for 'Obj.array' I get one of the following Exceptions upon deserialising:

1. [ProtoMember(1,AsReference=true,DynamicType=true)] (as written above): Argument Exception at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType. This occurs even if Base is not abstract
2. [ProtoMember(1,DynamicType=true)] :  Argument Exception at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType.  This occurs even if Base is not abstract
3. [ProtoMember(1,AsReference=true)] : 'Cannot create an abstract class' exception. If Base is not abstract, I get an "Object does not match target type." exception.
4. [ProtoMember(1)] : No exception, but I need to serialise things as a reference (also, the deserialised Obj has FOUR items in 'array', but I think this bug has already been reported)

I need to be able to serialise the array using AsReference... If I'm not doing something wrong, can anyone think of a decent workaround for this?
Thanks!

Comment: There is a glitch with combining AsReference and inheritance. It is the very top thing on my protobuf-net list, but I need to finish prep for Øredev first. In other words "it is a known bug; it will be fixed soon, but probably not today"